# Is this a Toeplitz matrix?

Tags: matrices, control-theory, toeplitz-matrices

In my control system course, I have encountered the concept of state space representations. I have encountered this matrix :
$$
\mathbf{A}=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&\cdots&0\\
0&0&1&\cdots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
-a_{n}&-a_{n-1}&-a_{n-2}&\cdots&-a_{1} \end{bmatrix}
$$
I was wondering if this matrix is some version of the Toeplitz matrix. Furthermore, I was wondering if it has some special properties regarding its eigenvalues since there's an assertion that the poles of the transfer function are identical to the eigenvalues of $A$

Comment: Google "Rational Canonical Form".

Comment: No, this is not a Toeplitz matrix. The eigenvalues are solutions of the characteristic polynomial, hence solutions of $x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+a_2x^{n-2}+\dots +a_{n-1}x+a_n=0.$